# Error during mvn install Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin, archetypes

This is my setup:

```
Maven: 3.5.4 
android-plugin-version: 3.8.2
Java version: 10.0.2
```

I'am building a fresh archetype: e.akquinet.android.archetypes (version 1.1.0)

After I running `mvn clean install` I got one of those two errors (depending on the combination of android-maven-plugin and maven):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/aether/spi/connector/Transfer$State
```

or

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:apk (default-apk) on project my-android-project: Execution default-apk of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:apk failed: A required class was missing while executing com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:apk: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
```

I tried different combinations of (**before I try a combination I always cleaned my local repository**):

```
android-maven-plugin: 3.8.2 , 4.0.0 , 3.2.0
maven: 3.5.4 , 3.2.2 , 3.3.9 , 3.1.1
```

I like maven very much and I would love to make this work

Answer (score 0):

Java 10 is not supported. Have a look at the latest release of the Android Maven plugin and the contained example project and use Java 8.